# Custom text restrictions in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for some solution for a custom restriction in Google Sheets.
Example: if cell A2 contains "no" then cell B2 is restricted for editing. As far as I googled, I need to deal with TextValidationBuilder somehow, but I have no scripting skills and have not found any samples so far.
Any ideas how to set this?

Update:

1. I need this restriction works for the whole line, so if A2 is no, then the whole 2 is disabled for editing
2. Column A should be edited only by specified users, so not everybody should get access to it
   Screenshot of what I'm trying to do [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdHFt.png)

Comment: I would think that the [Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) class is more what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

- For the full columns **A2:A**, **B2:B** until the last row with content:

  ```
  function myFunction() {   
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');     
    const checkA = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
    const me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
    checkA.forEach( (ch,index) =>{                
    if (ch === 'No')
       {
         var protection = sh.getRange(index+2,2).protect()    
         protection.addEditor(me);
         protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
         if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
            protection.setDomainEdit(false);
         }
       }});
  }
  ```

---

### References:

- [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)
- [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but after playing it, I still can edit other cells :(

Comment: @KirillKuchin  You can edit because you are the owner. Other users won't be able to edit these cells.

Comment: @KirillKuchin you want the users to be able to edit `only` B2 If A2 is `no` ? I though you wanted to protect only B2 from editing .

Comment: @KirillKuchin if you want to protect all cells except for `B2` then use my first solution.

Comment: well, tried from different accounts and still I can edit these. I also need give some permissions like some people can edit, but other - cannot. And restrict edition for the whole row. 
I made a sample here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VB-9f4hA1rkvEKekN4IiEbpXtFjY8DjHOAamBSRx1hU/edit#gid=0

Comment: @KirillKuchin In your sheet you use 'No' but my code checks for 'no' since that was part of your question. Anyway, I changed the code for you in the file you provided and now it works.

Comment: @KirillKuchin also, stackoverflow is not a coding service. You question clearly states you want to prevent a `cell` from being edited. You didn't say `row` and you definitely didn't say `specific user permissions`. Generally, it is a good idea to show your efforts. You just said, I want this and that but you didn't search how to do any of these things. It is really difficult for the community to help you if you don't put any effort.

Comment: thanks for your notes, I'm new here, so I don't realy know how this work
Details about row and specif users are optional, I would try to figur out how to do this by myself if only I got main concept working. For know your code still doesn't work or I don't understand how to use it. I'm still able to edit cells